# Override TableRates if StoreView not Default

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, plugin, table-rates

I want to override the `TableRate` values, if the `StoreView` is not the default one.
So I wrote a plugin for `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate.php`.
The code is not working...

```
class Shipping2
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
) {
    $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
}

public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate $subject, $result) {
    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    //$result = $collectRatesResult->getResult();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    /*$method->setCarrier('tablerate');
    $method->setCarrierTitle('Best Way');
    $method->setMethod('bestway');
    $method->setMethodTitle('Table Rate');*/

    $amount = 100;
    $method->setPrice($amount);
    $method->setCost($amount);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

}

I do not know what is wrong with it...
Can someone push me into the right direction?

Comment: So, I tried to work it out, but without success. I can only add an additional `Shipping Method` if I work with `append`.
If I overwrite the `$result` with `$method`, my `total-price` changes to the price of the custom shipping, and does not contain the `product price` anymore...

Comment: Have you get any solutions for this ?